# I can add a new document to Firebase Firestore but not update one, why?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase's Firestore database and haven't had any issues until today - I have no problems reading data or adding new documents to the collections. What I can't seem to do now is update an existing document (which was working previously).

What could be causing this?

Code for the update >

```
    func updateSite(site: Site) -> Bool {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    do {
        try db.collection("Sites").document(site.id ?? "Unknown ID").setData(from: site)
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
```

}

Edit- I'm working in Swift (iOS) via Xcode 13.3. There haven't been any changes to the code to deal with Firestore but I did switch to using Firebase-cloud-storage for images, other than that nothing I can see impacting here.

The error on update is returned as an Auth Error - (See below)

: 2022-03-23 06:06:44.462999+1300 Scout[15793:933890] 8.13.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. Too many attempts. Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed. The server responded with an error:

- URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/(edited)  9:exchangeDeviceCheckToken
- HTTP status code: 400
- Response body: {
  "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "App not registered: 1:587919427052:ios:ad2ac8f3abd4cbd5fc6cc9.",
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }

As far as I can see there aren't any denied requests showing in the Firebase web console and no other Firestore requests (reads / Writes) from the App are preformed without issue.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell us what language you are using? Are you receiving some kind of error? And what is the Firebase version that you are using? Have you made some updates recently?

Comment: Cheers, have edited for extra detail

Comment: It seems like an issue with the Firebase SDK, I suggest you create a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk).